# Ubuntu 18.04 - the odyssey of black screen when in idle

Tags: 18.04

Good day everybody.

I'm making a custom iso of ubuntu using cubic.
I'm all done except for 1 part: when in idle for x minutes the screen goes black. Of course i dont want that so here's all i've tried/done:

```
xset dpms 0 0 0 && xset -dpms  && xset s off && xset s noblank
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

useless to say that none of the command above worked, the computer still goes in ? sleep ?  with the black screen.

Any idea on how to solve this ?

(it's been 5 days of testing and googling without success)

Thanks for your time

Comment: You are not using the correct approach to set gsettings values, and I think this is what is causing your issue. Have you searched the answers at [Questions for Cubic](https://answers.launchpad.net/cubic) on how to set gsettings values?

Answer (score 0):

You need a gsettings override file.

Here is a the technique for setting gsettings values. You may need to add more keys and values depending on your needs (based on your original question). I've only shown two keys as an example...

1. Open a new empty document in gedit (or other text editor) on your host system.
2. Add the following contents to your file:

   ```
    [org.gnome.desktop.screensaver]
    lock-enabled = false

    [org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power]
    idle-dim = false
   ```
3. Save the file with the following name:

   ```
    90_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override
   ```
4. In Cubic's terminal page, type the following command and press the enter key.

   ```
    cd /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   ```
5. Open Nautilus (or other file browser) on your host system, and naviage to the directory where you saved the file `90_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override`.
6. Drag the file onto Cubic's terminal window.
7. Click the <kbd>Copy</kbd> button in Cubic.
8. The file will be copied to the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` directory inside Cubic.
9. Then type the following command inside Cubic's terminal window.

   ```
    glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   ```
10. Finish making your other customizations, and generate your new Live ISO using Cubic.

Whenever you bootup or install your OS from the new Live ISO, Ubuntu will read default gsettings values from `90_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override`.

If you add other settings to `90_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override`, remember to execute the `glib-compile-schemas` command each time.

As you may expect, the user can always personalize your defaults using tools like Gnome Tweaks, Dconf Editor or the `gsettings` command.

Comment: sorry, keep having black screen after 5 minutes

Comment: Do you think it is your hardware that is doing that?... If you have an external monitor, it may blank the screen independent of the OS, if no signal is detected. Turning off the monitor and turning it on usually fixes this, but I haven't found a way to change this from within the OS. If it is a laptop screen, there ~may~ be a setting in the BIOS for this behavior.

Comment: i can confirm is not the monitor and double checked bios

Answer (score 0):

The setting is an active screensaver ("Blank screen") that starts after X minutes (Settings -> Screensaver). After disabling it, my displays stay active.